# Swagger User Interface without JSON/YAML

Tags: api, documentation-generator

My boss asked me for a tool to do swagger documentation through UI **without typing in JSON/YAML based data**.

He wanted something like a **form with fields** where if we type in relevant details like endpoint, method, payload and all relevant details, it will generate a swagger documentation for the same or generate a swagger.json file which can be used for generating documentation.

Tried googling and did not find any such tool. Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this myself from https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md

Few implementations like:
1) Apicurio Studio - https://github.com/Apicurio/apicurio-studio
2) OpenAPI GUI - https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-gui

or if using WSO2, we have a GUI inbuilt to do all this and it generates a swagger doc.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, what I see used is [RESTLet Studio](https://studio.restlet.com/), which work like you described, but have the huge con of being online-only.